# "Toy for your kid" or "Toy for your kids" as you don't know how many kids they have?

Tags: grammatical-number

Say you are a toy shop owner, who wants a slogan.

Comment: BTW: ['who', not 'whom'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/using-who-and-whom/). [When in doubt, use 'who'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/using-who-and-whom/94#94). "Say you are a toy shop owner, who wants a slogan".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you were planning to give just one toy per set of siblings, I would say "toy for your kid" as it would imply one toy per child.

Comment: One Laptop per Hamster

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say "Toys for your kids"? Multiple toys for multiple kids.

Answer (score 5):

*Child*/*children* is usually the more formal/correct term. But for a slogan, the slang "kid(s)" is fine.
To answer your question, it depends on the context. If you're advertising that you have toys for people's kids.

For a slogan:

> Come to the Toy Box, home of the best Toys for your kids

The plural case is always better and more generic.

If you have a promotion:

> Come in today and buy a new toy for your kid

is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use a word that is the same for plural and singular.

> "Here's a toy for your offspring."

Comment: +1 for elegant workaround - although it probably won't work as a store slogan :)