# Is there a simple explanation on where to use "who" vs "whom"?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using who and whom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/using-who-and-whom)

I can usually guess which to use where, but I can never explain it to others, is there a simple explanation (with examples) that makes sense?