# Finnegan's Wake: "the least successful of whom was..."

Tags: word-choice, relative-clauses, grammatical-case

Does the following sentence sound awkward because of the positioning of *whom*?

> Beans grew up in a Roman Catholic household with four brothers; the least successful of *whom* was the bank president.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/most-of-which-or-most-of-whom](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/most-of-which-or-most-of-whom)

Comment: Can you clarify? are you concerned with the location of 'whom' in that sentence? whom vs who? or whom vs which?

Answer (score 3):

I have no reference, but I've heard the claim that *whom* should be used when referring to people, and *which* the rest of the time.

In any case, the sentence sounds fine to me. I easily understand what the writers intention is.

Comment: Compared to the rest of *Finnegan's Wake* this sentence is pellucid!

Answer (score 1):

The OP asks if the sentence sounds awkward because of the **positioning** of *whom*. The only alternative word order is *of whom the least successful was the bank president*. That seems to me to give a different emphasis, suggesting that the other three brothers might have been moderately successful. By beginning the clause with *the least successful*, he suggests that none of them might have been up to much.

As for *whom* versus *which*, the corpus-based ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ (based on the big Longman Grammar) says:

> Especially in the written registers, there is a very strong tendency
>   for a relative clause with a human head noun to use *who* rather than
>   *which*

Comment: The *whom/which* distinction is essentially trivial, but that's an excellent point about how the positioning *of whom* seems to subtly influence our assumptions as to whether the other brothers were relatively or objectively successful.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you, and congratulations on reaching your 20,000.