# ...again, the proper use of "which" vs. "whom"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Most of which” or “most of whom”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/most-of-which-or-most-of-whom)

The following is a sentence from an email I recently sent, not knowing if it was the proper use of the word.

> As I mentioned, I have two (2) clients in the OMAHA area *for whom* I have been moving freight for about 16 months.

My question is whether I should have used "for which" instead of "for whom".

I make every effort to use my native language properly, but I am often unsure of the proper use of some of these words.

Comment: Why do you think it should have been _for which_?

Comment: What do you even mean by "properly"? What´s the actual source of your insecurity?

Comment: Is there really need to write *(2)* after *two*? I managed to read and understand *two* without clarification. And is there really need to shout *OMAHA* instead of *Omaha*?

Comment: Related: ["Most of which" vs. "most of whom"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/most-of-which-or-most-of-whom).

Comment: AS to your? "Is there really need to write (2) after two?"

Comment: @RegDwighт♦: [Greg R.'s answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/16516/2637) there is much better than mine here, and easily covers this question (apart from my stunning graphics, obviously! :), so I'm voting to close as a dup.

Answer (score 2):

Noting [this chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clients%20for%20whom,clients%20for%20which&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) comparing *"clients for **whom**"* against *"clients for **which**"*...

[image]

...I think it's fair to say *"whom"* is the preferred word with "human" referents such as *client, buyer, customer, user, purchaser, shopper* etc.

Comment: Of course, what many people would actually say is _As I mentioned, I have two (2) clients in the OMAHA area I’ve been moving freight for for about 16 months._

Comment: @Barrie: I'm sure they would. But of course if I wanted to be picky, I could point out that that's what they would actually **say**. In speech, the second "for" would be *very* "unstressed" (as would the first "that" in the sentence before this) - what looks stylistically clunky in the written form can be completely unexceptional in actual speech.

Comment: I thought you might say that, and I was aware of the awkwardness of the repeated _for_, but then writers of emails often replicate the forms of speech.

Comment: @Barrie: Yeah - usually when I *read* the word **for** the "voice in my head" hears it as **four**. But in speech I habitually reduce it, so I'd normally say *"...moving freight **fə** them"* even if the word only occured once. With the repeated construction here, it's more like *"moving freight for **f'rabout** 16 months"*. And I wouldn't even enunciate the /r/ if it weren't for "about" starting with a vowel. Don't waste phonemes, I say (you never know if we might run out of them one day, like fossil fuels! :)

Answer (score 0):

Collins has personal and organisational alternatives in its first-mentioned definition of *client*:

**client [ˈklaɪənt]
n
1. a person, company, etc., that seeks the advice of a professional man or woman**

Notice that it uses **that** rather than **who** after the closer antecedent **company**. I'm sure that this licenses 'for which' in the original **if** 'clients' refers to companies or other organisations. However, I'm equally sure that 'client', no matter whether it refers to an individual or an organisation, connotes enough personality *always* to license **who** or **whom**. I'd opt for the construction indicating person(s) / personification .

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into the use of *that* rather than *who* -  there are 10s of thousands of ["he is the person that..."](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he+is+the+person+that%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books. *Which* is always for things, and *who* is always for people, but *that* can do for either.

Comment: How may I reply to a specific commenter written in response to my original question?