# Who vs. Whom – 'some of who have endured relentless conversation about B these past eight months and all who have long endured me.'

Tags: whom, who

The full sentence is

> Finally, I am hugely indebted to my family, some of who have endured relentless conversations about B these past eight months and all of who have endured me.

Is **who** correct in both places in the sentence? Or should it be **whom**?

Comment: An even better question which has been previously asked and is not closed is [Most of which OR most of whom?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/most-of-which-or-most-of-whom)

Answer (score 1):

"Whom" is the correct word in both places. There are many situations where "who" is commonly accepted instead of "whom", but in my experience the phrases "some of whom", "all of whom", "many of whom" are still used even by people who would not normally bother with using "whom".

Your extract appears to be part of a speech of thanks, and I would recommend using "whom" in a formal setting such as this.