# How should I construct "the who"?

Tags: grammar, whom

In correspondence this morning, I found myself using a very verbal construction:

> Your Recommendation is entirely up to you in terms of the who and why.

With due respect to [the he:him::who:whom rule here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/using-who-and-whom/83#83), how should I have constructed this sentence in formal, professional correspondence?

- Should I have used "who" or "whom"?
- Should I have offset "who" and "why" with quotes?
- Is there a special word for the usage of [who/why/when,etc] when they are used in this objective/subjective fashion?

Comment: You shouldn't use this construction at all in formal, professional correspondence because it's informal. In a formal context you'd probably want words like *assigned personnel* and *rationale*.

Comment: Are there really workplaces in the English-speaking world where *"the who and why"* would be considered unacceptably informal? I can't believe it.

Comment: I've never seen "the whom" used to mean "the question of whom" until now, but astonishingly it is done. [The What, the Whom, and the Hows of Survey Research](http://www.eric.ed.gov/ERICWebPortal/search/detailmini.jsp?_nfpb=true&_&ERICExtSearch_SearchValue_0=EJ475549&ERICExtSearch_SearchType_0=no&accno=EJ475549), for example.

Comment: @Jason The email was meant as an "explain this to me like I'm a Fourth Grader" communication to a client; so it was a hodge-podge of formal/professional (due to it being with a client) and informal/verbal (because it was explaining something in its basest terms). That said, I used 'who' so as to not confuse the person being explained to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works like this. You take a phrase, like *who would be the best man for the job?*. You reduce it to one word, *who?*. You do the same for *when should this job be done?*. You then use these phrases as nouns: *what matters most is the who, not the when*. Sentences like *His no really shattered my dreams* and *I want no ifs or buts!* are results of the same process.

You could choose to add quotation marks and question marks with these questions-turned-one-word-nouns, but that is usually not done. They are mostly either not marked at all, or written in *italics*.

The implicit question behind this *who* is rather free: it could be *whom do you consider the best man for the job?*, or *who should do it?*. Since there is no way to tell what the implicit question was if you use only *who*, you are theoretically free to choose *who* or *whom*, unless context forces you into assuming one implicit question or another. Conventionally most people would use the neutral form *who* in most cases, which is what I recommend.

The use of *who* and *when* in this fashion is informal. If you're aiming at a rather formal style, you'd better avoid such constructions. Incidentally, the current style of your quote is rather informal as well.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether the person (the *who*) would be a subject or not.

- If you mean “you can decide freely who should write it”, then it's “in terms of the who [will write it] and why”
- If you mean “you can decide whom it should be sent to”, then it's “in terms of the whom [it will be sent to] and why”

All in all, it's probably *who*.