# Should I use "who" or "whom" as the only word in a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, objects, subjects, whom

I understand that "who" is for the subject and "whom" is for the object. However, sometimes they are used as the only word in a sentence. For example:

> Person 1: Yeah, he ate the entire cake.
>
> Person 2: Who(m)?

Which form is correct?  I can see it being short for both "Who is the person who ate the cake?" and "Whom are you talking about?"

Comment: If you say 'whom' in this context, it makes it sound like you're referring to the entity that was _eaten_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this example, it should definitely be **who**.

A single word question like that is typically seen, grammatically, as an ellipsis for a full-sentence version, as you say.  But elided words/phrases are almost always things which have already just been said, so following “He ate the entire cake,” the natural ellipsis would be “Who [ate the entire cake]?”, not “Whom [are you talking about]?”.

Even in cases where it would make formal sense, though, “Whom?” is rarely used alone:

> The tiger ate him up entirely!

> Who?

“Whom did the tiger eat?” or “Ate whom?” sound fine to my ear (as do their equivalents with “who”), but “Whom?” alone sounds quite stiltedly pedantic.  As [ShreevatsaR has described very well](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/using-who-and-whom/94#94), *whom* is — while not obsolete yet — certainly of limited use, and when in doubt, *who* is pretty much always an acceptable alternative nowadays, and is often more idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

*Who* is correct. In reality, *whom* is largely obsolete, and shouldn't be used in isolation.

See this question for a general discussion of *who/whom*: [What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/using-who-and-whom). As shown there, it's rarely actually necessary to use *whom*, and in the case of a one-word answer you should always fall back on *who*.