# Can a phrase be the object of a clause and how would its subject change?

Tags: objects, whom, whoever-vs-whomever, predicate

Take the  sentence:

> I speak all over to whoever will listen.

...at first blush, I thought, "Ah — *whoever* should be *whomever*."

However, I then noted that in the phrase "whoever will listen", *whoever* is correct.

I think the central issue is that if the sentence had ended without the "...will listen" then it would be correctly stated, "I speak all over to whomever."  As it is, it seems like the last part of the sentence ("whoever will listen") ends up being the object of the 'to' rather than the single word: 'whoever'.

Is this sentence grammatically correct, and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Whoever" Vs. "Whomever"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84376/whoever-vs-whomever) Also [Should I use whoever or whomever here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44893/should-i-use-whoever-or-whomever-here)

Comment: One of those threads has an accepted answer that is wrong, the other thread doesn't have an example that is like the OP's. Perhaps someone could simply answer the OP's question, and provide a vetted grammatical source to back up that opinion.

Comment: Here's a post that might interest you: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/166875/57102

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to *The McGraw-Hill Handbook of English Grammar and Usage*, "whoever" is correct.

Although we see "to whoever", it is correct because "whoever" is **not** the object of the preposition "to". The object of the preposition is the **entire** noun clause "whoever will listen". And because "whoever", as you point out, is the subject of "will listen", it is written in the subjective case.

*The McGraw-Hill Handbook* gives the following example:

We will sell it to **whoever** bids the highest.

We will sell it to **whomever** bids the highest.

The *Handbook* declares the first sentence to be correct.

Comment: The second one is incorrect. The best advice is never to use _whom_ or _whomever_ unless you are completely confident you know why and how it is to be used, and can cite the rules. Since almost nobody meets this qualification, it's best to avoid it altogether; it's very rare anyway, and more than half of the uses one encounters are incorrect, so correct usage carries no benefit.

Comment: @JohnLawler
I'm sorry, but I cannot agree that "correct usage carries no benefit". I would say that the best advice is to learn the rule and apply it. That is, after all, the purpose of websites such as this one.

Comment: Nonsense. That is certainly not the purpose of this website. And "learning the rule", as you call it, requires a very sophisticated knowledge of syntax, since the only context where _whom_ is required in English is when it's the object of a pied-piped preposition in a relative clause, which is an optional construction, since it's easier and more common to strand the preposition. The rest of the time the rule allows **either** _who_ or _whom_, unless _whom_ is ungrammatical, in which case only _who_ is allowed. _Whom_ is, for all intents and purposes, dead. Better to learn the rule for _thou_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: so after a [long and valiant struggle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=whom&searchmode=none) of 700 years, _whom_ has now finally succumbed. /me proposes a moment of silence in remembrance.