# Is this a correct use of 'whom'?

Tags: word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the rule for using “who” or “whom”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/whats-the-rule-for-using-who-or-whom)

"The negative may be insecurity, in lieu of an absolute authority whom can to confirm your beliefs."

This is the sentence. I am unsure whether to use who, or whom.

Thanks

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate, but if you read the answers there are you are still uncertain, you may edit your question to indicate why those answers are not sufficient.  Your question may be reopened then.

Answer (score 1):

It should be 'who', because it is the Nominative Case.

> ...who can to confirm...

is wrong, though. Can takes the bare infinitive (without to).

> He can confirm your beliefs. (not him, right?)

Therefore,

> The negative may be insecurity, in lieu of an absolute authority who can confirm your beliefs."