# Double "whom" sounds clunky, but is correct?

Tags: whom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the rule for using “who” or “whom”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/whats-the-rule-for-using-who-or-whom)

I believe the following sentence is correct, but am slightly unsure as it sounds a bit clunky - plus, the irony of it being incorrect would be unbearable.

> "Thank you to Bill and Ted, whom I'll never be able to thank in person but without whom my education would not have been possible."

Comment: It's correct. It's also clunky.

Comment: I don't think it's actually clunky - structures that repeat words for effect have a long tradition in rhetoric.

Comment: Yeah, but any use of _whom_ is formal, and pronouns are supposed to be practically inaudible -- just a pointer to the noun, then get out of the way, nothing to see here. Doubling a formal pronoun calls attention to a word that should not be called attention to.

Comment: It is neither incorrect nor clunky.  If you insist on saying this all in one sentence, then the sentence that you have exhibited is the grammatically correct way of saying it.

Comment: General Ref. -1 research not shown.

Comment: It's been said before, but worth repeating. 'Whom' was invented to make us all sound like butlers.

Comment: Thanks to @BarrieEngland for the "butlers" quote, so good that it sent me on a quest for the author. The complete quotation, by Calvin Trillin, is "*Whom* is a word invented to make everyone sound like a butler. Nobody who is not a butler has ever said it out loud without feeling just a little bit weird."

Answer (score 3):

It's correct, but *whom* is formal and in modern speech can sometimes sound overly formal, especially when repeated.

As the [Guardian style guide editor](http://www.guardian.co.uk/media/mind-your-language/2011/aug/15/mind-your-language-who-whom) says:

> It's true that when they speak most people don't
>   use "whom", and with good reason: it would
>   make them sound like pompous twerps ("to
>   whom do I owe the pleasure?"). Written English,
>   however, is a different matter – and not just
>   because people write angry letters when you get it wrong.

From the comments, some people don't find it clunky, others including you and me do. Therefore I suggest rewording it or using *who*, particularly for speech, and arguably also when written.

This applies to British English, and I believe also to others.

Comment: I agree and would even take this a step further to say: don't use "whom".  Save it for poetry.  'Whom' is a holier-than-thou thing to say, anymore.  In fact, try to avoid saying anything the Creoles don't say.  Some say words like 'color' are bastardized English.  Others will argue, and much more eloquently, I feel, that this kind of word is the result of segregation and classism.  The international community seems to lean towards American English in its standards.  It's easier, it's humbler, and it incorporates a more racially diverse population, which is what 'Lingua Franca' is all about.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it simple?

> Thank you to Bill and Ted. I'll never be able to thank them in person. But without them, my education would not have been possible.

[Purists may resist starting a sentence with the conjunction "But". If you are of that school, you could use a comma instead of a period.]

Comment: 'sOK ... Little x when you move your cursor over the grey 8 mins ago (or whatever it is when you read this) after your name. *The wastebasket is the writer's best friend.* - Isaac Bashevis Singer