# "Whoever" Vs. "Whomever"

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses, grammatical-case, whoever-vs-whomever

On the subject of "whoever" and "whomever", I was reading this but I am still confused: http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoever.asp

What is the correct use of whoever/whomever in the following sentence?

> I like your copy, congratulations, whoever is writing it.

Whoever? Whomever?

Is there a difference between US and UK English?

Comment: Actually the page you linked to explains it just fine. See also [What's the rule for using “who” or “whom”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/whats-the-rule-for-using-who-or-whom)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is that it has to be *whoever*, because the relative pronoun takes the case of the function it serves in the subordinate clause.  That whole clause is “whoever is writing it”, where *whoever* is the subject of the clause, just as *is* is its verb.

Swap in *he*-vs-*him* on things like this to see which one works right: you would never say **him is writing it*, so it cannot be *whomever*.

No, this is not different in any standard form of English, although some hypercorrectionists are wont to get it wrong and wrongly stick *whomever* in there where it has no business being.

Comment: So _whoever_ in that context is right? And it's right for both US and UK English?

Comment: The simplest thing to do if you're not sure of where/when/whether/why to use _whom_ or _whomever_ is simply not to use either one. Ever. They are more often used incorrectly than correctly, even by native speakers; non-native speakers should avoid both. [_Whom_ is dead](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001437.html).

Comment: @JohnLawler: This is a bit extreme. Language would be rather boring if noöne ever dared daring constructions or used unusual usages.

Comment: What's daring about _whom_? Why not try _hath_ or _dost_, if you want a thrill?

Comment: If I may raise the dead, can I ask for a reference to the relative pronoun taking the case of the function it serves in the dependent clause? To demonstrate why I'm asking this, I extrapolate from your answer that it should also be `I'll congratulate whoever wrote that piece`, not `whomever`, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @JonathanY.  The direct object of the verb *congratulate* is the entire clause *whoever wrote that pieces* as  a single constituent.  Words within constituents do their job there, not the job of the constituent itself. Therefore *whoever* is a subject and the entire clause is the object.

Comment: @tchrist - Could you add that helpful information to your answer, please?

Comment: @JohnLawler - Your solution takes a totally different tack.  I invite you to put it in an answer.

Answer (score -2):

I'm quoting [a tip sheet](https://www.esf.edu/wrc/tipsheets/whom.htm#:%7E:text=Pronoun%20case%20in%20a%20dependent,whom%22%20or%20%22whomever.%22) here:

> When who and whom (or whoever and whomever) appear in subordinate clauses (groups of words which contain a subject and a verb), their case is determined by their function within the clause.

Example 1:

> Whomever the party suspected of disloyalty was executed.

Example 2:

> He tells that story to whoever will listen.

In other words, what matters is the subordinate clause not the main clause.

Comment: At least find examples which contain "whoever" and "whomever". And you need to reference the place you took the picture from (otherwise it's plagiarism, which is unethical).

Comment: yes added examples and deleted the image. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I doubt you'd find many people uttering (or writing) 'Whomever the party suspected of disloyalty was executed'; 'whomever' is disappearing faster than 'whom'. 'Whoever the party suspected of disloyalty was executed' would win the popular vote overwhelmingly (and usage drives grammaticality).