# Correct Question word: Who or whom?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, grammatical-case

I'm wondering which option is the right one:

> - *Who* is he having lunch with?
> - *Whom* is he having lunch with?

Comment: http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoVwhom.asp

Comment: Thank you for the link; unfortunately, it doesn't help because I've already verified different sources of grammar, and I therefore would automatically say "WHOM is he ...". But in one of my "Business English Workbooks" it says "WHO is he ..." So I'm confused, and I'm wondering whether both is possible?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/94/300

Answer (score 2):

Answers:

> - Who is he having lunch with?
> - With whom is he having lunch? [formal/archaic]

Comment: Also _Whom is he having lunch with?_ [formal].

Comment: @Marcus_33: Thank you; this answer (which I indeed overlooked when searching the forum) is not only helpful concerning my specific issue but also interesting with regard to this hypercorrection subject.

Comment: @Red Sissy/@John Lawler: Thanks a lot for your answers, too, which definitely helped me out of a fix! :-)