# "With whom" vs. "with who"

Tags: whom

It suddenly came to my mind that this is quite strange:

> 1. Obama, **with whom** I was at school, has just come to live in our street.
> 2. **Who** are you hanging out **with**?

Obviously, both sentences are correct, so is "with whom".

But... why do you say "who are you hanging out with", not "whom"?

Comment: It is perfectly legal in Standard English to say "Whom are you hanging out with?". Although I perceive a register dissonance between the formal "whom" and the informal "hang out". The dissonance, however, is equally present in your first example.

Comment: In my first example ?

Comment: You mean Obama ?   lol

Comment: This question has been asked many times before - search the site and read a previous answer!

Comment: Both sentences are **not** correct.  To be 100% grammatically correct, your second sentence should use "whom".  Yes, almost everyone *says* "who" for that, so it *sounds* correct to most people.  But it is still wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly ask *Whom are you hanging out with?*— it's completely grammatical— though the kind of person who would say it would probably use the even more stilted *With whom are you hanging out?*

[The difference between *who* and *whom*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56) has been covered extensively in previous questions. *Whom* has been suffering a [steady decline](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2013/04/for-whom-the-bell-tolls/309266/) ([in conversational English](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2012/04/grammar)) for some decades, and sounds formal or affected. As such, you'd be unlikely to hear it used with the colloquial *hanging out*, as *whom* is largely absent from less formal registers these days. Additionally, it is familiar to see *who* at the head of a sentence as an interrogative pronoun, so it is either less noticed by or less objectionable to pedants.

Comment: What's 'stilted' about 'with whom'? In the stiltedness stakes I rank sentences that end with prepositions as the most stilted of all. Besides plenty of Limericks will never scan without 'with whom'.

Comment: *With whom are you hanging out?* does sound stilted, but very few people would actually say it.  Rather, someone inclined to use *with whom* would probably also be more inclined to say *with whom are you spending time?*

Comment: It is an observation of mine that "whom" is actually experiencing a resurgence.  I hear and see it more and more frequently.  I am also seeing used *correctly* more and more frequently.