# "my brother, *who/whom* she later married": Which is correct?

Tags: grammar, whom

I know very well that my question is in the duplicate department, but I need to be sure on the usage of "Who/Whom" in this particular example.

> She met my brother, *who/whom* she later married.

Please strike-through the wrong option.

The source where I encountered this example states that both options are valid.

My understanding is that we say "She married to him", so "whom" is the correct option.

Please advise.

Comment: The duplicate should explain your example as well as anyone else's. It's a fine idea to read the duplicate, then ask if you're still uncertain and why.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that you use "who" when you are referring to the subject of a clause and "whom" when you are referring to the object of a clause. 
whom is the correct usage

Answer (score 1):

"She met my brother, *whom* she later married." is correct. Here, *brother* is the direct object, and hence *whom* is correct.

> First, to know whether to use "who" or "whom," we need to talk about the difference between subjects and objects because you use "who" when you are referring to the subject of a clause and "whom" when you are referring to the object of a clause. - [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-whom).

So, *him* is the object, so we would use *whom*.

> My understanding is that we say "She married to him", so "whom" is the correct option.

It's only appropriate to say

> - She is married to him, or
> - She married him

and not *She married to him*.

There has already been a good discussion on this, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly), and [one of the top answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/94/117371) clearly says that the traditional rule is to use *whom* in the "objective case".

Comment: Hi, vrraghy, and welcome to the site. I'm sorry I down voted you, but "sounds right" is ok for idiomatic usage and slang; this question is based on grammar. If you remove "sounds' and replace it with guidelines that are correct, I'll remove my down vote. (Just use the edit button above this comment.)