# Who’s fighting "whom" in Syria? Who's fighting "who" in Syria?

Tags: grammar

In the [headline](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-34462867) of BBC News:

> "Who’s fighting whom in Syria?"

Is it correct to use *whom* instead of *who*?

This is a specific example of the who/whom question that has been asked in a more general sense elsewhere. Every time somebody asks about who/whom does not mean it is a duplicate!

Comment: This seems to have been answered here. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly

Answer (score -2):

It is technically incorrect, though most people will let it slide enough for this to safely be ignored a good chunk of the time unless somebody's being a pedant. Languages evolve, too. I almost never use "whom" myself.

"Whom" isn't common in casual speech.

Often in non-formal speech *who* doubles as an object pronoun.

Comment: 'It is incorrect' is incorrect nowadays. Acceptability has evolved. Read Professor Lawler's post at the duplicate.

Comment: I don't do "correct", which I regard as a judgment about fashion, not language. But those who use _whom_ at all will normally use it there - and they are often the kind of people who believe in "correct". In what sense do you claim that it is incorrect?

Comment: *Technically*. I would usually not use whom at all.

This issue doesn't really have an absolute answer.