# The difference between whom and who

Tags: word-choice, grammar, differences

my first language isn't English and there's a question no teacher has been able to answer me; when exactly do you use "Whom" instead of "Who" and why? Thanks. Also, I'm new here and if you have any tips on how to post my questions correctly it would be of great help. Thanks again.

Comment: Over at our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) this has been answered: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-can-one-differentiate-between-who-and-whom, and of course here as well: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly, making this a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I would just add that despite what you'll read in some of the answers that Stephie refers to, *whom* is not truly dead; it's alive and kicking! In constructions where the pronoun is object of (and immediately follows) a preposition, only *whom* is acceptable:

"To whom / *To who is he talking"?

In that example, only *whom* is possible: *who* is ungrammatical. Other than that, when the pronoun is object of a verb, the choice between *who* and *whom* depends on style level, *who* being less formal than *whom*.