# 'Whoever' or 'whomever' in a more complex sentence

Tags: whoever-vs-whomever

I understand the difference between 'who' and 'whom', but in the following sentences I'm not sure whether to use 'whoever' or 'whomever':

> 'Give *wh-ever* did that a pay rise.'
>
> 'Tell *wh-ever* is teaching the class that I will be a little late.'

I look forward to reading your responses!

Comment: It's "whoever" in both cases. See [What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly?lq=1#comment425262_56)

Answer (score 1):

The rule is to use "who" where "he" makes sense and "whom" where "him" makes sense.  The same rule applies for "whoever" and "whomever."

One would say, "*he* did that" instead of "*him* did that."  Likewise, one would say "*he* is teaching the class" instead of "*him* is teaching the class."

Therefore, the correct word is "whoever" in both cases.