# The usage of Who in 'Who can Curly see?'

Tags: grammaticality

'Who can Curly see?' is the title of a book for kids. Curly is the name of a caterpillar. The book is to show that Curly saw several kinds of insects. When I read it I think the *who* should be *whom* instead.

I am not an English native speaker and I am not sure the use of *who* is correct or not in this book's title.

So could you help to clarify this?

Thanks.

Comment: See [ShreevatsaR's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/94/77227) here: "the usage of who in situations where previously whom was standard has been increasing, especially in spoken usage"..."The Language Log posts (1, 2, 3) linked in another answer, as well as William Safire quoted on the Wikipedia page, recommend avoiding whom or recasting your sentence if it seems necessary"..." using who in place of whom is, at worst, being too colloquial (and at best, being hip and cool!)"...

Comment: Summary: there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your understanding of the rule, but you should know that native English speakers don't always follow this rule.

Comment: Short version or @sumelic's short version: nobody uses *whom* anymore. Forget about It.

Comment: I have been a native English speaker for more than fifty years, and I have _never_ used the word 'whom'. You will occasionally hear it from aged Americans, but otherwise, as @Dan says, you can forget about it.

Comment: I'm a speech-language pathologist who has specialized in child language development for 15 years, and although I can't cite you any research on the age of acquisition of the term "whom" for children I would bet it's really late. Thus, I would think it unreasonable to use "whom" in a children's book title.

Comment: @Katherine Lockwood , Just to confirm:  Do you mean the word 'Whom' is deprecated in all cases or just in the book title?   thanks.

Comment: "Deprecated?" No. Just not age-appropriate for a title in a children's book.

Comment: @swenker I would say "whom" is generally deprecated