# Who/Whom Usage... I

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, should I use 'who' or 'whom?:

> An Open Letter To Those [Who/Whom] I Have Hurt

I googled the usage and it said to test by replacing with He/She or Him/Her representing Who and Whom respectively. I don't think that applies in this situation.

Comment: Can you tell us what site suggested that test and maybe also what happened when you followed through with the test?

Comment: Why don't you think trying the replacement test applies in this situation? What situation do you think it would apply in, then?

Comment: I think I should use 'whom' because it is the object of the verb 'hurt'. Is this correct intuition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly)

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to use "whom" at all (many people don't), then it is grammatical in this example, because it is the object of the verb in the relative clause: "hurt".

Answer (score 1):

Do not depend the old he/who him/whom trick blindly but, in this case, it does actually help.

> An Open Letter To Those **Whom** I Have Hurt

Is your answer and if you substitute third person pronouns you can see why.
If you split up the sentence and just use the last phrase, you can see how **who** would not be *strictly* correct. This is because *him/whom* is the grammatical object and therefore uses the objective pronoun.

> I have hurt **him** [not *he*]

This then leaves me to answer to greater question: is *whom* always correct?
As with most questions regarding written or spoken modern English, this is a matter of [register](/questions/tagged/register) and formality. Generally, in more formal uses, **whom** is most appropriate, however, more casually and more often when spoken, misuse of *who* is perfectly acceptable.

I prefer to stick to the old ways of using the correct case when possible but public attitude has generally turned towards a multi-purpose who.

Comment: How can it be a misuse and yet acceptable?