# “Whom” or “who” I wrote this for?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

See title.

Is the correct sentence
“Guess whom I wrote this for?”
or
“Guess who I wrote this for?”
I prefer the former.

Comment: Don't ever use _whom_. **Especially** not in a fixed phrase like _guess who?_

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/94/300

Comment: If you must use 'whom' then at least say "Guess for whom I wrote this". No one will get it, everyone will hate you but at least the grammar will be 'right'.

Comment: I also prefer the "whom" version.

Comment: @JohnLawler any sources on why not to use ever "whom" ?

Answer (score 1):

*Whom, whose,* etc are different "cases" of the interrrogative/relative pronoun *who*.

"Cases" are different forms of the same word, according to the function it fulfills in the sentence.

- *Who* is the nominative case, used when the word is a subject.
- *Whose*, the genitive case, used to mark possession.
- *Whom*, the accusative or dative case, used for direct and indirect objects, respectively.

In modern English, the cases for "who" other than the nominative are increasingly being dropped, especially in speech.

That said, the correct form to choose is "*whom*" in your example, because "*whom ... for*" is an indirect object in the sentence.

In many cases, "*guess who*" would be the proper form to use.

For example, If I said:

*Guess who came for dinner.*

"*who*" would be the subject of the subordinate phrase "*who came for dinner*".

So many speakers, by analogy, tend to always use the "*who*" form in sentences containing "*guess who*".

Answer (score -2):

Here **who** is used as an object. As an object **who** is grammatically correct. **Who** is widely used. If anybody is asked should it be who or whom, the answer is **who**.

We generally use who as an object (NOT whom). In a very formal style, we use 'whom' as an object.

**Who** can be the **subject** of a question. Who telephoned you? Who is helping you?

**Who** can also be the **object** of a question. Who did you telephone? Who are you helping? Who do you like best? Who are you speaking to?

The man who you saw yesterday is my brother. (or The man you saw yesterday is my brother)

Comment: Please do not use Stack Exchange to try to draw attention to your personal sites. It is in poor taste. It risks being flagged for spam, or worse.