# In the sentence "I hope it's who he ends up with", should it be whom instead of who?

Tags: whom, who

I think it should be whom, because we're talking about the one he ends up with. He is the subject, but the one he ends up with is the object. That's why whom.

Comment: [Related and possibly a duplicate](/q/247207)

Comment: Nobody uses *whom* except in very formal contexts. I'm guessing this isn't very formal, so *who*. See e.g. [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly).

Comment: The actual assertion would be *She ends up with **him***, not *...with **he***. That's the easy way to decide, unless you want to go down the even easier route of falling in line with the rest of us (who rarely/never use ***whom*** today, except *perhaps* after the preposition ***to***).