# Is it "She is whom he fights for", "She is who he fights for" or neither?

Tags: pronouns, whom

Another way to say nearly the same thing would be "He fights for her" which makes me think of two things in particular:

- Because "her" is used, the correct choice should be "She is whom he fights for"
- However, because "her" is used, beginning the sentence with "She" makes no sense gramatically

The title of the post is my question. In case both examples I gave are wrong, I would highly appreciate an alternative!

Comment: I'd go with *She's the one he fights for* or *She is what he's fighting for*.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of [this unanswered question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/588129/in-the-sentence-i-hope-its-who-he-ends-up-with-should-it-be-whom-instead-of), and if you check the "whom" tag you may find one with an answer.

Comment: "It is she for whom he fights" if you want to rearrange these particular words into a grammatical (but old-fashioned) sentence.

Comment: @ThePhoton As Churchill is claimed to have said, this is the kind of tedious nonsense which I will not put up with.